# What is the best way to develop C for Linux on Windows?

Tags: c, sockets, visual-studio-code

I am in uni, and we are learning C. Up until now, I haven't had any problems writing in VS Code and compiling in Cygwin. But now that we are on sockets, my IDE is next to useless. Having `#include <sys/socket.h>` in my code removes all the red squiggly errors to focus on the missing #include. When wrapping it in a `#ifdef` along with `#include <winsock2.h>` is inconsistent with its error showing, this will miss basic compilation errors like missing semicolons and return types.

Right now it seems my best option is to change the compiler and write it all to fit windows.
Is there an easier way to continue without drastically changing my work environment?

Comment: "What is the best way" is an opinions based question and is thus off-topic for Stack Overflow. Suggest you re-word your question to explain the problem you are facing. I gather it is something to do with how the IDE is behaving with certain code but it is not entirely clear from the description. Provide a small code example, how the IDE is behaving and how you expect/want it to behave instead.

Comment: [WSL2](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/09/03/wsl2) made writing posix compatible code from a Windows dev box using VSCode near trivial. I can't recommend it highly enough.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install virtualisation software. For example VM Ware Workstation player which is free for personal/educational use
2. Install Linux
3. Install Eclipse
4. Program Linux programs on Linux running on the Windows machine.
   [image]